# Socket.io authorization, "No Authorization header was found"

Tags: socket.io, authorization

Trying to add authorization to my real-time app, I get this message in chrome console:

```
socket.io-parser decoded 4{"message":"No Authorization header was found","code":"credentials_required", "type":"UnauthorizedError"}
```

Here is my code (I use angular-fullstack):

socket.service.js (client side)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('smthing')
  .factory('socket', function(socketFactory, Auth) {
    var ioSocket = io(null, {
        //Auth.getToken() returns $cookieStore.get('token') from angular auth.service.js
        'query': 'token=' + Auth.getToken()

  });
...
```

socketio.js (server side)

```
socketio.use(require('socketio-jwt').authorize({
    secret: 'smthing',
    handshake: true
}));

socketio.on('connection', function (socket) {
     console.log('smthing');
...
```

"smthing" never prints. If I remove the authorization part, everything works correctly. I thought it was pretty straight forward... Any help would be great !

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I am encountering the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this in my own environment.  I use this snippet, though I had issues until resolving the root issue.

```
io.set('authorization', socketioJwt.authorize({
    secret: jwtSecret,
    handshake: true
}));
```

The root issue was that the `token` required for **socketio-jwt** was not being added to the request `query`.  If you inspect **socketio-jwt/lib/index.js**, you'll see some code like:

```
//get the token from query string
    if (req._query && req._query.token) {
      token = req._query.token;
    }
    else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
      token = req.query.token;
    }
```

This means that you should be able to log the value for `query` and `_query` here, and see your token.

If you cannot, you must be sure on in your socket.io client that you are setting the token to the query.  The typical way for this is to add it to the `connectParams`.

In the iOS/Swift client, this looks like this:

```
self.socket = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:@"localhost:8091" 
                        options:@{
                                   @"connectParams" : @{@"token" : <my_token>}
                                  }];
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually the right syntax:

```
var ioSocket = io(null, {
    query: {       
        token: Auth.getToken()                   
    }
});
```